# Only users with "Sharepoint Administrator" can manage alert on a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Even with the control total on the Sharepoint Online library, my users cant create alert : error message with id.

How can i change that ?

Answer (score 0):

What is error message?

Ensure the user has at least Read permission on the site.

If you only grant user permissions on the library (not on the site), the user will have limited access on the site. He can only access the library. Since the Url of creating alerts page is like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_layouts/15/SubNew.aspx?List=<list GUID>&Source=%2Fsites%2Fsite%2F_layouts%2F15%2FMySubs%2Easpx`, and the Url of managing alerts page is like: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_layouts/15/MySubs.aspx`. They are not pages under the library. If user has no permissions on the site, he will get access denied error.